# Is it possible to charge your cell-phone using a computer?

Tags: mobile-phone, charging

My cell phone remains plugged (almost all day).

Is it possible to charge my cell phone by plugging it into my USB port via a data cable ?

My Model: Nokia 2690

[image]

Comment: Depends on the model you neglected to mention in your question. My iPhone charges when plugged in, so it's possible.

Comment: How did you connect Nokia 2690 to your computer? I can't find any mention of data cable on Nokia's website.

Comment: I have another cell phone 5233, I used its data cable

Comment: If I'm right and that phone comes with micro USB port, then see my edit.

Comment: Old Nokia phones can't be charge through the USB cable even any model. But I heard that the latest model has this feature.

Comment: Can we charge nokia 5233 with usb cable?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you need to have the right adapter.  Some cellular phones have these, but you'll need to make sure your model has such an adapter available for it (most of the older cellular phones don't).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the model. With the original data cable it should work - just check the mode in which the phone is - my nokia wont charge itself in USB storage mode - only in phone mode.

Comment: Is it possible to charge in Nokia PC suite mode ?

Answer (score 1):

Fellow Nokia user here.

Basically, if your phone can be charged by data port, it will automatically start charging as soon as cable is plug in to the computer. If it doesn't then you cant charge it using data cable.

There is a workaround for this issue for some phones. There are cables available (and even Nokia makes them) which have at one end USB port and at the other end port used by telephone and connector like the one from the charger. If there is such a cable for your phone and you can obtain it, then that's the solution.

Otherwise, you could try to find some third party cable which will imitate a charger and connect to the computer.

EDIT: There are two types of cables which may be of interest for that phone. The [CA-126](http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/accessories/all-accessories/memory-cards-and-cables/cables/nokia-charging-connectivity-cable-ca-126) and the [CA-100](http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/accessories/all-accessories/memory-cards-and-cables/cables/nokia-cable-ca-100). The CA-126 cable can charge the phone and provide connectivity while CA-100 only has charger.

Also, I'm pretty sure that we went outside of this site's topic with this question.

Comment: Thanks :),  and my question is related to computer so I don't think its off topic (its like in the middle).